# Can I query for Enum + 1?

Tags: mysql

If I have a dayEnum defined as `'Sun','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat'`

Is there any way to mention an increment of this Enum? Something like this `WHERE dayEnum IN ('Sun', 'Sun'+1)`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the internal numbers of your enum;

```
WHERE dayEnum IN (1, 2)
```

> For example, a column specified as ENUM('Mercury', 'Venus', 'Earth') can have any of the values shown here. The index of each value is also shown.

```
Value       Index
-----------------
NULL        NULL
''          0
'Sun'       1
'Mon'       2
'Tue'       3
....
```

[Source](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/enum.html)